# Como realizar Upload de imagens com Cloudinary e PHP

Tags: php

Meu cliente é sem noção. Manda fotos de 4MB ao sistema, e reclama da velocidade.

Estou pensando em usar o [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/invites/lpov9zyyucivvxsnalc5/gkbc7psrttu9jdt3fz9g) para solucionar este problema. Há bibliotecas para PHP na documentação. Mas estou sem um raciocínio bom para utilizar o serviço.

Alguém já utilizou e pode me dar umas orientações sobre esta implementação?

No meu atual, mando desta forma:

```
    <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

// ESTE ARQUIVO DEVE ESTAR EM admin/vovos/_lib/file/img E SETADO EM CADASTRPDELICIAS_CONTROLLER
$target_path = "app_img/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "Upload and move success";
} else{
echo $target_path;
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Mudei meu PHP para:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

require 'Cloudinary.php';
require 'Uploader.php';
require 'Api.php';

\Cloudinary::config(array( 
  "cloud_name" => "meu_name", 
  "api_key" => "meu_key", 
  "api_secret" => "meu_secret" 
));


$target_path = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload("http://res.cloudinary.com/ramosinfo/app_img/");



\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "Upload and move success";
} else{
echo $target_path;
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Conforme documentação, mas continuo sem conseguir mandar...